# Is there a way to get images(64*64) from a server faster while running in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, image-processing

I want to fetch images into my application cache in a faster way.

I do a map kinda app by loading at about 25 images at a time in a UIscrollView in which each image takes about 1 second for downloading.

All images are of size 64KB and 256*256 dimensions. I am doing caching, So after the first time when i scroll there will be around 7-8 images to load and that too takes each second each. So in the middle of scrolling the map it stops for around 7-8 seconds.

Is there a way that I can increase the speed of getting images, so that I will be able to load atleast 4-6 images a second?

Comment: Get a faster server? I mean there's not enough information here to know what the bottleneck might be and you don't even say what API you're using, what format the images are in (compression?) etc. Does the server support glib compression? Are you using HTTP? 1.0? 1.1?

Comment: "So in the middle of scrolling the map it stops for around 7-8 seconds" I think he means that the app freeze...

Comment: Sorry, I didnt made it clear. The app is not freezing. When I have to load new images, I just disable the scroll, then load the images, then enable. This loading of images from a server is taking me time. So all that time, the scroll is disabled and so cant scroll. Now if u understud, what I meant do u have an idea what to do?

Comment: I have the same answer to your new problem. Do this in the background and just don't disable the scrolling...

Comment: @ Nimrod
No, I didnt mean a faster server. I fetch the images into my app using a URL. In this URL, I can change the parameters so that it will fetch the continous images. I am using a UIScrollView with 25ImageViews on it and each gets the image downloaded into it.
 Dont think of this app as a normal map kind which uses some API. I am manually doing all those processes. Images are in png format. Ya, I am using HTTP.

Comment: +1: Not sure why there were downvotes here, seems like a decent question.

Comment: @Gcamp - it's likely he doesn't know what to load until the user chooses a scroll direction - at least that's how a tiled map works - the user scrolls to the new location, you load up tiles on demand. You cannot load the entire map in the background because it's too big.

Comment: @ diciu - Ya, exactly thats what I meant. Even though I do threading it would be of no use because of the reason u said. 
@ Ferrans - Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this, but 64kb for a 256x256px image? No matter how nicely you thread things, you're gonna hit the bandwidth cap of 3G trying to pull down images like that. Make 'em JPGs instead of PNGs, or use GIF!

Comment: @ Ben Gotow - How can I do that? Its the server which is giving the images in .png format. Even if I have to do some conversion, first I have to get the images na??

Comment: It's still not obvious why you do not want to use threads to retrieve the images you need. Can you explain what you're really trying to do?

Comment: I think there is 2 reasons I cant use the threads. Instead of map just see my app as one which is continuosly loading images(like jigsaw puzzle) from a server.
1. When I drag and when scrollView meets its any one of its ends then only it will decide which images it should load on. So at that point of time what is the use of doing it with an another thread when the main thread can do it and is not having anyother thing to do.
2. Whether i download the images normally or using thread, what difference will it make coz anyway it will take the same amount of time?

Comment: it may take the same amount of time, but the app itself will be nicer to use as it'll be smoother. Do it in a background thread and just display them as they load. But also +1 for changing the server to give you the images in jpg form instead of png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use CATiledLayer, which spins off a separate thread for rendering each tile. It's how the Maps app does its drawing. You can have it download the images within the drawing code, and it won't block the main thread, so scrolling will be smooth. It'll still take time to download the images, but if you have a low-resolution proxy image you can show that while it loads the real image.

Answer (score 3):

You need to free the main thread and do this on a background thread. When you're doing heavy work on the main thread, it will block and you app will appear unresponsive. (If you don't know on what thread you're running, your are probably on the main thread.)

Take a look at [the apple concurrency guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: So for the above reasons, u would have understud now that when we do a tiled map its of no use doing the threading.

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser does this by spinning up a number of background fetch threads in parallel (reducing the overall download time) and displaying the map tiles as they come in (giving the illusion of higher responsiveness).

You can get a better feel for this by installing Firebug on Firefox, and then activate it while loading a complex page.  It'll show you a graph over time of how long it takes each page component to be fetched, and this shows the parallelism.